# Internet Connection Sharing + Port Forwarding range

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, port-forwarding, netsh, ics

I'm using Internet Connection Sharing from a Windows 10 computer in order to give a device internet connection and would like to use port forwarding from this connection as well but I need to add a large range of ports (20k+ ports).

Is there a way to add these ports via the command line? A way to add a range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who's struggling as much as I was. I've figured it out using JScript (C++ went way over my head)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ics/adding-and-removing-port-mappings-jscript-

The documentation is slightly wrong as theres `"&amp;"` instead of just "&" and some missing semicolons, but it got me to where I need to be.